# Facebook form feed dialog - error with link attributes

Tags: php, html, facebook

I'm having a problem passing my URL variables to the Facebook feed dialog. I can see it in the link when I press the button, but once I post it on Facebook, I get everything until the `&`.

Here's my code:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=142170752632916&
redirect_uri=http://domain.com/&
link=$currentUrl&amp;
picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&amp;
name=$title&amp;
description=$description">Share</a>

$currentUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ;
```

My URL looks like this:

```
www.Domain_Name.com/index.php?subaction=showfull&id=1368007502&start_from=3&template=Default&#disqus_thread
```

Once I post it on Facebook, I get the link as:

```
www.Domain_Name.com/index.php?subaction=showfull
```

And no id or other attributes are passed.

What can i do to fix it?

Edit:

Here's what I get once I try to post my link on the feed:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?%20%20app_id=142170752632916&%20%20redirect_uri=http://domain.com /&%20%20link=http://www.domain.com/FrontEnd/index.php?subaction=showfull&id=1368007502&start_from=3&template=Default&&%20%20picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&%20%20name=bbb&%20%20description=bbb
```

Comment: You need to [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) everything you pass as an URL parameter. Right now, the URL has two separate query string parts. Facebook's URL parser probably ignores the second question mark, and parses the items after & as parameters of the outer URL.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the facebook's [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), seems like the real magic is in the callback function

```
function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }
```

This is the one that adds the additional paramenter `?post_id=12345` to the url `https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/` . Thus follow the example below that facebook provides ensuring the parameters in the callback function to the one that you want in your URL,
namely `subaction=showfull&id=1368007502&start_from=3&template=Default&#disqus_thread`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          redirect_uri: 'YOUR URL HERE',
          link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
          picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
          name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
          caption: 'Reference Documentation',
          description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```